# Check whether argv[1] is a hex string

Tags: c, ip

I have a simple program which takes IP address as its only argument. The IP address can be in two formats: doted decimal or hex. Depending on which was used, I need to perform different operation.

Thus I need to check if the argument is

```
1) IP in dotted decimal format
2) IP in hex format 
3) other (illegal/malformed argument)
```

How would I best check that ?
Should I use some kind of regular expressions? A correctly formed hex address must have 8 hex characters, `[0-9a-f]{8}`. Correct decimal dotted IP must contain 4 numbers [0-255] and 3 dots.

Comment: Suppose '11.11.11.11' is entered.  Would it be valid?  Would it be hex, or dec?

Comment: I think the OP is looking for these two inputs: `(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}` and `[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}`

Comment: @Mahonri Moriancumer - a hex IP address does not contain dots. Thus `11.11.11.11` is a valid dotted decimal ip.

Comment: @MartinVegter, understood. Oftentimes, HEX values are prefixed with '0x', for example, '0x11111111'.  Could that convention be expected here?

Comment: If the latter is to test IPv6, you will rightly need to consider the possibility of [address abbreviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_representation), which is not trivial with regex. Regarding using regex, the phrase "I had a problem, so I used regular expressions to solve it. Now I have *two* problems" is often more accurate than given credit. If you use regex, stick with **basic** (i.e. do basic *qualifying* with regex, and validation with something else). Use regex for *patterns*; use validation code for proper range limits. And best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I am only working with IPv4 addresses here. But it is a good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isxdigit(character)` from the `<ctype.h>`, which checks whether `character` is a hexadecimal digit or not.

---

***UPDATE:***
If my presumption is correct, and the "dotted" address is like: `(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}` and the hexadecimal address is: `[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}`, then you are looking for something like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool
isxip(const char *address)
{
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(address); i++)
        if (address[i] == '.')
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When it contains dots then it is most likely not a hex string.

Comment: OK, but it could contain dots and still be illegal, for example `a.a.a.a`

Comment: Yes. And when it contains dots and points only, it could stll be illegal. e.g. 1.2.3.456